# Why don't these words look to have have the same size?

Tags: math-mode, math-fonts

Is it due to my eyes that these words W1 aren't of the same size here?
Also I tried left aligned for the second column but somehow it looks skew to me. Please tell me if you have any idea to make it look nicer.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}

  \begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \caption{TEST FUNCTIONS}
  \label{tab:table1}
  \begin{tabular}{c l}
                            \toprule
STTC & FUL\\ \midrule
H1 & $W_1$ \\\midrule
H2  & $\frac{1}{W_1}$ \\\midrule
H3  & $\frac{1}{1-W_1}$  \\\midrule
H4  & $1-W_1$ \\\midrule
H5  & $\frac{W_1-1}{W_1}$ \\\midrule
H6  & $\frac{W_1}{W_1-1}$\\\bottomrule

\end{tabular}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The font size in text style math fractions are of course smaller than the normal font size

Comment: But all formulas in the second column is formated in math style  with $ symbols. Is it normal to look different sizes like that? How can I make them of the same size?

Comment: `$... $` is always text style math (unless under certain circumstances)

Comment: That is what I meant. All the formulas in the second column are put inside text style math so should they have the same size?

Comment: @hana This  is unrelated to tables. You are using inline textstyle math designed to fit in a normal height line. fractions use a smaller font just as superscripts do. Would you ask the same about $2+x^{2}$ where the second 2 is smaller? 2+½ is the same, the second 2 is smaller. You can use `\dfrac` instead of`\frac` to get display fractions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is unrelated to tables. You are using inline textstyle math designed to fit in a normal height line. fractions use a smaller font just as superscripts do. The W is smaller just as the second 2 is smaller in  2+½ . You can use \dfrac instead of\frac to get display fractions.

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}

  \begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \caption{TEST FUNCTIONS}
  \label{tab:table1}
  \begin{tabular}{c l}
                            \toprule
STTC & FUL\\ \midrule
H1 & $W_1$ \\\midrule
H2  & $\dfrac{1}{W_1}$ \\\midrule
H3  & $\dfrac{1}{1-W_1}$  \\\midrule
H4  & $1-W_1$ \\\midrule
H5  & $\dfrac{W_1-1}{W_1}$ \\\midrule
H6  & $\dfrac{W_1}{W_1-1}$\\\bottomrule

\end{tabular}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks much nicer.

Comment: Not that improtant but in the second column at H3 and H4,  1-W1 aren't aligned. I understand that is due to the fraction line is longer than text expression. Is it possible to force to text to aligned

Comment: @hana, the expressions are aligned, but to the left, check the parameter `l` for the second column. You probably mean or want a center alignment.

Comment: @FHZ I think you misread my question. It is left aligned but for the whole formula not text. If you look at the row H3 and H4 you can see that expressions 1-W1 in H3 and H4 are not aligned with each other.

Comment: @hana as FHZ says I'd use a centred column here. I would also (never) use `[!h]` which means not top not bottom not on a page on its own, so gives latex almost no chance to set the table and usually produces a warning that it is being changed to `ht`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Let me show you the alignment I was talking in the image below. https://ibb.co/CVHCZsf

Comment: @hana yes I realize that's what you meant and coincidentally using a `c` column would make those align. But otherwise aligning a top level expression with a subterm in the denominator of another expression is a pretty unusual thing to want, If you _really_ want that you could adjust by eye with some negative space. But I would not. Just use a centred column.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go with center aligntment then.

Comment: I want to highlight a bit like {H1,H2}, {H3,H4}, {H5,H6} each of them form a group. Do you have any recommendation to replace \midrule to make that?

Comment: @hana the site doesn't really support  asking new questions as comments, it doesn't really have any answer other than "whatever you want" in a formal document midrule is fine, other less formal alternatives include giving coloured background panels to the table (`colortbl` package) or a new 1st column with a group "heading" or ....

Answer (score 9):

> Please tell me if you have any idea to make it look nicer.

In addition to the use of `\dfrac`, I played around with the table structure a bit to make better use of the full textwidth within the assumed two-column layout of IEEEtran:

[image: layouted Table 1: Test Functions with 6 columns, 3 rows and several lines of lorem ipsum text below and above]

Additional tweaks:

- Reduced `\tabcolsep` to make STTC, FUL column pairs bond tighter together
- Added `\hskip 3em` between column pairs
- Added `\addlinespace` around the midrules for more visual hierarchy between table rows and fraction lines

With that display order, it is easier to spot that H2, H4, H6 are simply the inverse of H1, H3, H5.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
  \lipsum[2]
  \begin{table}[!h]
    \centering
    \caption{Test Functions}
    \label{tab:table1}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
    \begin{tabular}{cc@{\hskip 3em}cc@{\hskip 3em}cc}
      \toprule
      STTC & FUL & STTC & FUL & STTC & FUL \\ 
      \midrule \addlinespace[.75em]
      H1 & $W_1$ & H3  & $\dfrac{1}{1-W_1}$ & H5  & $\dfrac{W_1-1}{W_1}$ \\ 
      \addlinespace[.75em] \midrule \addlinespace[.75em]
      H2  & $\dfrac{1}{W_1}$ &  H4  & $1-W_1$ & H6  & $\dfrac{W_1}{W_1-1}$ \\
      \addlinespace[.5em] \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
  \lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice looking table but I'd move the change of `\tabcolsep` into the `table` environment such that it remains a local redefinition. With this code *all* tables are affected.

Comment: @campa: thanks for the suggestion, done!

Answer (score 5):

In the second column you may define display style. Using `tabularray` package this is simple to do:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!h]
    \centering
    \caption{Test functions}
    \label{tab:table1}
\begin{tblr}{hline{1,2,Z} = 0.8pt, hline{3-Y}={dashed, 0.15pt}, %solid
             colspec={c Q[l,mode=dmath]}, % column is in math displaystyle 
             row{1} = {mode=text}         % first row is in text style
             }
STTC    & FUL                   \\  
H1      & W_1                   \\ 
H2      & \frac{1}{W_1}         \\ 
H3      & \frac{1}{1-W_1}      \\ 
H4      & 1-W_1                 \\ 
H5      & \frac{W_1-1}{W_1}    \\ 
H6      & \frac{W_1}{W_1-1}    \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]